# How to play audio using AVAudioPlayer in SwiftUI project

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swiftui, avaudioplayer, swift5

**Audio is not playing using this approach.
The play() function is executing without any error.**
Please help

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "a", ofType: "mp3")
@State var isPlaying : Bool = false

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
         self.isPlaying.toggle()    
         let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.path!)
         do {
             self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
             self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
             self.audioPlayer.play()
         }catch {
             print("Eror")
         }        
      }, label: {
           if isPlaying {
                    Image(systemName: "pause")
                    .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).bold())
           }else {
                Image(systemName: "play.fill")
                 .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).bold())
           }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Is the audiofile there? Please select the project, go to Build Phases tab and under 'Copy Bundle Resources' you must see the audio file. If it is there then the problem is this.

I tried your code, it played the sound and then crashed. i changed it like this to make it work

```
 @State var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

 @State var isPlaying : Bool = false

 var body: some View {

     Button(action: {

         if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "a", ofType: ".mp3") {

             self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

             self.isPlaying.toggle()

             let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

             do {
                 self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                 self.audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                 self.audioPlayer?.play()
             }catch {
                 print("Error")
             }
         }

     }, label: {
```

### ----

Have you considered separating your Audio model from your UI? It would make your code much clearer if you put it into separate Swift file

```
import AVFoundation

 class Sounds {

   static var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

   static func playSounds(soundfile: String) {

       if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundfile, ofType: nil){

           do{

               audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
               audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
               audioPlayer?.play()

           }catch {
               print("Error")
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

And just one line to use it in UI

```
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.isPlaying.toggle()
        Sounds.playSounds(soundfile: "0.wav")

    }, label: {
```

Comment: I cannot get your class Sounds version to work in my SwiftUI app. I'm trying to add the Sounds.playSounds(soundfile: "GetReady.m4a") in an .onAppear() but it won't play my sound. Is there a trick to adding sound files to SwiftUI projects maybe? I created a new folder in my Project navigator then dragged/dropped the .m4a files into it.

Comment: can you put the project in githube?

Comment: I created a public test project that is essentially set up the same way as my real project: https://gitlab.com/jammyman34/sounds-test

Comment: Some files are missing in github project, can you reload? the ones in red color are the missing files 
 https://ibb.co/FYWFX13

Comment: ok, try this project please https://gitlab.com/jammyman34/test-sounds-project

Comment: It seems your sounds files have not been added to the project,  please select each the sound file and on the right side check the box before  SoundsTest  like this https://ibb.co/PFbRNr8

Comment: Wow!! That was exactly it. THANK YOU!!!